# Swing JComboBox drop down shows only below value

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, jcombobox

[image: JCom]

**Attached is picture showing how drop down is looking currently.**

Values added in `JComboBox` is from A to L. D is set a selected value on load. When I open drop down, it starts showing value from D till L. A,B and C are hidden up.
Width of drop down can't be increased and also `setMaximumRowCount()` can't be set.

I just want when user open drop down it should be shown from A not from D.

***Source code is***

**Java Applet Class**

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class Main extends Applet{
   public void init(){
       JComboBox<String> c = new JComboBox<>();
       c.addItem("A");c.addItem("B");c.addItem("C");c.addItem("D");c.addItem("E");
       c.setName("Combo Box");
       c.setSelectedItem("D");
       c.setSize(1000, 1000);
     // g.drawString("Welcome in Java Applet.",40,20);
      add(c);
   }
}
```

**Running HTML file**

```html
[![<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div >
<APPLET CODE="Main.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500">
</APPLET>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>][1]][1]
```

Comment: Easiest solution would be to put D first, since it's the pre-selected value.

Comment: order can't be changed.